# Difference between buddhasasana and buddhadhamma

Tags: theravada

Is it correct to say that the buddhasasana (the teaching of the Buddha) is conditioned and impermanent in contrary with Dhamma itself which is unconditioned and permanent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct to say that the buddhasasana (the teaching of the Buddha) is conditioned and impermanent in contrary with Dhamma itself which is unconditioned and permanent.

No.

Sasa = verb (Teach)

Sasa**na** = noun (Discipline&Doctrine;teaching)

Dhamma = Discipline&Doctrine

BuddhaSasana = **Discipline&Doctrine of the Buddha**

Sutta. Tī. Pā. [Udumbarikasuttaṃ](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=11&A=773&h=Aha%E1%B9%83%20pana%20nigrodha,ahamanus%C4%81s%C4%81mi%20aha%E1%B9%83%20dhamma%E1%B9%83%20desemi):

> Let a sensible person come—neither devious nor deceitful, a person of integrity. I **teach** (aham-anu**sāsā**mi) and instruct them doctrine **(Dhamma)**. By practicing as instructed they will realize the supreme end of the spiritual path in this very life, in seven years.
>
> Ahaṃ  pana  nigrodha  evaṃ  vadāmi etu viññū puriso asaṭho amāyāvī   ujujātiko   ahamanu**sāsā**mi   ahaṃ   **dhammaṃ**  desemi  yathānusiṭṭhaṃ tathāpaṭipajjamāno     yassatthāya    kulaputtā    sammadeva    agārasmā anagāriyaṃ   pabbajanti   tadanuttaraṃ  brahmacariyapariyosānaṃ  diṭṭhe  va  dhamme sayaṃ   abhiññā   sacchikatvā   upasampajja   viharissati   satta  vassāni .

Dhamma in your context is a part of Buddhasasana. To consider abot it, the  Buddha taught in Sutta. Ma. Mū. [Cūḷasaccakasuttaṃ](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=12&A=8527&eng=accesstoinsight_than):

> 'Form is inconstant. Feeling is inconstant. Perception is inconstant. Fabrications are inconstant. Consciousness is inconstant. Form is not-self. Feeling is not-self. Perception is not-self. Fabrications are not-self. Consciousness is **not-self**. All conditioners are inconstant. All phenomena (**Dhamma**) are **not-self**.' This, Aggivessana, is the way in which I discipline my disciples; this part of my instruction is generally presented to my disciples."
>
> rūpaṃ  bhikkhave aniccaṃ   vedanā   aniccā  saññā  aniccā  saṅkhārā  aniccā  viññāṇaṃ aniccaṃ   rūpaṃ   bhikkhave   anattā   vedanā   anattā   saññā  anattā saṅkhārā    anattā   viññāṇaṃ   anattā   sabbe   saṅkhārā   anattā sabbe   dhammā  anattāti  evaṃ  kho  ahaṃ  aggivessana  sāvake  vinemi evaṃbhāgā ca pana me sāvakesu anusāsanī bahulā pavattatīti.

By above Sutta:

1. All aggregates are conditioners (each others) because they are same inconstant.
2. All aggregates are Dhamma because both of them are same not-self.
3. So some Dhamma, Nibbāna and Sammati, is not conditioned and not inconstant.

   -**Nibbana** is not conditioned, not constant, and not-self. It is reality which never arising, no aggregates at all. It's real because it is the opposite of all aggregates, not based on any aggregates. People can access Nibbana by the complete Vipassana, Magga.

   -Conception, **Sammati**, is not conditioned, not constant, and not-self. It is unreal and never arise, just imagination based on aggregates. Every people can access Sammati. Some people can use Sammati in meditating Lokiya-Jhāna to avoid craving in aggregates, but it is impermanent avoidance because minds create Sammati from thinking of aggregates, therefore it is possible to crave aggregates again in the future, **so Sammati is not the perfect opposite of aggregates.** However Lokiya-Jhāna is still important for Vipassanā meditation.

Comment: I think that *dhamma* is usually translated "doctrine", i.e. "what is taught", isn't it -- whereas *vinaya* is "discipline". So *dhammavinaya*, "the doctrine and the discipline".

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Did you try to answer the other part of the question -- about whether the dhamma and/or sasana are "conditioned and impermanent", or whether they are "unconditioned and permanent"?

Comment: I edited the answer about that topic. At first, I decide to avoid writing about it because I often write like this and it seems no one understand it. It's too hard, however it is a core of Phenomena (all things).

Answer (score 1):

sāsana (lit. 'message'): the Dispensation of the Buddha, the Buddhist religion; teaching, doctrine.

Navaṅga-buddha (or satthu)-sāsana, the ninefold Dispensation of the Buddha (or the Master) consists of Suttas (Sutta), mixed prose (geyya), exegesis (veyyākaraṇa), verses (gāthā), solemn utterances (udāna), sayings of the Blessed One (itivuttaka), birth stories (jātaka), extraordinary things (abbhutadhamma), and analysis (vedalla). This classification is often found in the Suttas (e.g. M. 22). According to the commentaries, also the Vinaya and the Abhidhamma Piṭaka are comprised in that ninefold division (see Aṭṭhasālinī Tr., I, 33). It is a classification according to literary styles, and not according to given texts or books.
https://www.budsas.org/ebud/bud-dict/dic3_s.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Is it correct to say that the Buddha Sasana (the teaching of the Buddha) is conditioned and impermanent. For example, there are many puthujjana who do not follow the Buddha's Teaching and say all things exist due to mind, including when they falsely translate Dhammapada Verses 1 & 2. This shows the Buddha Sasana is conditioned & impermanent.

> *Mara.... Your serried squadrons, which the world with all its gods cannot defeat, Now I’ll break with wisdom sharp, as with a stone a raw
>   clay pot.*
>
> *With all mind’s thoughts within the range, with well-established mindfulness, I’ll travel on from state to state many disciples leading
>   out.*
>
> *They, both diligent and resolute carry on my **Sāsana**, and though you like it not, they’ll go to where they do not grieve.*
>
> [Snp 3.2](https://suttacentral.net/snp3.2/en/nyanamoli)
>
> ---
>
> *Both for those who proclaim it And for those who listen to it, Confident in the Sublime One’s teaching (**sāsane**), The supreme good is fully
>   purified As they live diligently in the teaching (**sāsane**).*
>
> [Iti 98](https://suttacentral.net/iti98/en/ireland)
>
> ---
>
> *‘Oh, if I’d only live for another day and night, I’d focus on the Buddha’s **instructions** and I could really achieve a lot.’*
>
> *‘aho vatāhaṃ rattindivaṃ jīveyyaṃ, bhagavato **sāsanaṃ** manasi kareyyaṃ, bahu vata me kataṃ assā’ti*
>
> [AN 8.73](https://suttacentral.net/an8.73/en/sujato)

Where as, in contrary, the Dhamma itself is unconditioned and permanent, as follows:

> *Mendicants, whether Realized Ones arise or not, this law of nature **persists**, this **regularity** of natural principles, this **invariance** of natural principles...*
>
> *Uppādā vā, bhikkhave, tathāgatānaṃ anuppādā vā tathāgatānaṃ, ṭhitāva sā dhātu dhammaṭṭhitatā dhammaniyāmatā*
>
> [AN 3.136](https://suttacentral.net/an3.136/en/sujato)

In other words, the Dhamma always exists, even when there is no mind to experience it. Even if there were no Arahants and the world was 100.0% puthujjana, the Dhamma would continue to exist; but unknown & in secret.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the following verse I would say "Buddhs Sasana" is not the same as Buddha Dhamma.

"Sabba papassa akaranam
Kusalassa upasampadha
Sachitta pariyodapanam
Etam buddhanu **sasanam**"
I asked a similar question in Dhamma Wheel.

https://dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=35481&p=530361&hilit=Sabba+Papassa+Akaranam#p530361

Comment: It appears my answer is incorrect.